# Восстановление прав и владельцев файлов

Tags: linux, bash

Было скопировано с помощью `rsync -avz` (или `-rvz`) с сервера на сервер несколько сайтов, и у многих файлов поменялся владелец и сменились права.

Чтобы восстановить права, первое и единственное, что пришло в голову, это:

- На исходном сервере запустить `ls -lah /www/sait1 > permis.file`
- пробежаться таким образом по всем папкам, вложенным тоже.
- перекинуть результат на новый сервер, распарсить все, и уже обратным образом, пробегая по папкам, назначить нужные права.

Меня смущает сам метод.

Есть более правильное или другое решение сложившейся проблемы?

Про архивацию через tar не предлагать, про нее знаю, проблема возникла - ее надо решать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое и быстрое, что пришло в голову - это сделать на первой машине

```
# для данных о каталогах
find  / -type d -exec stat -c "%n %a %G %U" {} \; | awk '{print "chown "$3":"$4" "$1"; chmod "$2" "$1}' > dirs.txt

# для данный о файлах
find  / -type f -exec stat -c "%n %a %G %U" {} \; | awk '{print "chown "$3":"$4" "$1"; chmod "$2" "$1}' > files.txt
```

полученные файлы переносятся на целевую машину, изучаются, фильтруются по мере надобности. А потом накатываются с помощью bash

```
bash dirs.txt
bash files.txt
```

То есть, вначале накатываются данные для каталогов, а только потом для файлов. Иначе может сложиться ситуация, когда накатить права для файлов не получиться, так как нет доступа.

можно было бы теоретически это все в одну команду выполнить, но мне было лень дописывать фильтрацию каталогов "." и "..".

Comment: Да, думаю как минимум пригодиться.. но тоже не быстрый метод - но удобный...) сравню ради интереса так или через ls -  хотя все равно через find делать...

Comment: в  любом случае упираетесь в скорость файловой системы. ls в любом случае использует stat внутри.

Comment: согласен... то на тои выдет, но вам метод - красивше)

Answer (score 2):

согласно `man rsync`, опция `-a` является «сокращением» для набора опций: `-rlptgoD`.

среди них фигурирует опция `-p` — сохранение прав/разрешений (permissions).

т.е., права/разрешения после завершения копирования должны быть **в точности те же**, что и у исходных файлов/каталогов, и их изменение не требуется.

---

среди опций фигурируют и `-g` — сохранение группы-владельца, и `-o` — сохранение пользователя-владельца.

понятно, что произвольное изменение пользователя и/или группы у целевых файлов/каталогов возможно только в том случае, если процесс *rsync* в целевой системе выполняется с **полномочиями суперпользователя**.

но даже при наличии таких полномочий могут возникнуть «нестыковки»: по умолчанию *rsync* пытается использовать те же **имена** для пользователей/групп, как и в исходной системе, и лишь при отсутствии таких пользователей/групп использует **числовые идентификаторы** (в целевой системе может и не быть пользователей/групп с такими идентификаторами). кстати, это поведение можно изменить с помощью опции `--numeric-ids` (не будет производиться поиск соответствующих **имён**).

как быть в подобной ситуации? я вижу два варианта:

- *после копирования* можно изменить принадлежность файлов/каталогов (`sudo chown -R пользователь:группа каталог`). этот вариант также является единственным в том случае, если нет возможности выполнить *rsync* в целевой системе от имени суперпользователя.
- *до копирования* можно создать недостающие в целевой системе группы/пользователей с именами, используемыми в исходной системе (соответствие числовых идентификаторов необязательно — см. предыдущий абзац). кстати, если копирование уже было произведено, то достаточно лишь ещё раз запустить *rsync* с теми же параметрами/опциями — принадлежность будет изменена (проверил — меняется).

p.s. не стоит забывать про существование опции `-n` — при её наличии *rsync* не будет ни копировать, ни производить какие-либо изменения, а лишь сообщит о том, что *собирается* сделать.

Comment: Согласен, просто когда копировали, не учли, отсутствие пользователей. А упаковывать все в tar  с сохранением - было не реально. объемы очень большие. А вот создать заранее - это идея хорошая. если делаешь полностью сам.)

Comment: @Трезвый, ничто не мешает сейчас создать одноимённые группы/пользователей и повторить вызов *rsync* (сначала — с опцией `-n`). кстати, если вы в точности повторите те же параметры (и даже без `-n`), то копирования не изменившихся файлов производиться **не будет** — rsync достаточно «умён» для этого.

Comment: Мешает отсутвие доступа... так то - срадостью..  так сделаю на других серверах... но в анном случае только "кастыли".

Comment: @Трезвый, если нет доступа к исходной системе, то как же вы собираетесь получать утерянные данные о принадлежности файлов/каталогов?

Comment: ожидал данный вопрос) сервера были рядом - люди скопировали, сервера разлучили, теперь можно руками собрать данные и руками передать нановый... сервера друг друга не видят больше... как что и почему мне, к счастью, неизвестно...

Comment: @Трезвый, что значит «не видят»? даже если оба сервера находятся за nat-ами, можно использовать какую-нибудь доступную с обоих серверов машину как точку рандеву. *ssh forwarding* — весьма мощное средство. тем более, что для *rsync*-а не требуется повторно пересылать содержимое файлов.

Comment: @Трезвый, кстати, проверил, меняется ли принадлежность после создания недостающих пользователей/групп в целевой системе: да, запуск *rsync* с теми же параметрами (понятно, что от имени суперпользователя) «подбирает» те имена пользователей/групп, которые **совпадают** с именами в исходной системе. я изменил ответ соответствующим образом.

Comment: не видят - потому что они не то чтобы за натом, один не в сети. но это уже другая история)