# Как распаковывать файлы и папки в UNIX с сохранением CHMOD и выставлением владельца?

Tags: unix, tar, sudo, sh, chmod

Имеется .sh-файл, в котором происходит распаковка файлов из архива, загружаемого по FTP на сервер - всё это часть механизма резервного копирования и восстановления.

Итак, в .sh-файл'е есть команда:

```
tar -zxvf home.tar.gz -C $HOME
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после извлечения из архива:

- у папок и файлов был определенный владелец-пользователь?
- папки и файлы сохраняли бы настройки CHMOD?

Comment: `man tar` не пробовали ? там много интересных ключей. Вообще если вы разворачиваете tar под root он по умолчанию использует владельцев и права из архива

Comment: А если владелец должен быть не тот что в архиве а конкретно заданный, то `man tar` говорит что это делает ключ `--owner=NAME`

Comment: Да изначально запускаю .sh файл без каких-либо прав из под root'а, но у папок и файлов после распаковки получается другой пользователь и группа.

Comment: Добавил ключ:tar -zxvpf home.tar.gz --owner=www-root -C $HOME # в итоге файлы и папки не получили владельца: www-root к сожалению.

Comment: Другой - это какой ? который был в архиве или еще какой то ?

Comment: Я то же не внимательно прочитал `man` ... `--owner` добавляет в архив файлы с определенным пользователем. А извлекает либо с тем же что в архиве (--same-owner или при выполнении под рутом), либо именно с текущим пользователем (`--no-same-owner`). Так что стоит выполнять разархивирование не под рутом, а под пользователем www-data. Т.е. если скрипт выпоняется под рутом то `su www-data -c 'tar -xzvf file'`

Comment: Спасибо. Но что-то я думаю наверное мне лучше посмотреть в сторону rsync

Comment: *наверно мне лучше посмотреть в сторону rsync* — программа *rsync* тоже не создаст «недостающих» пользователей/группы (см. мой ответ под этим вопросом и [вот этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497472/178576)).

Answer (score 1):

> папки и файлы сохраняли бы настройки CHMOD?

права доступа к файлам/каталогам сохраняются программой *tar* внутри архива. соответственно при распаковке архива программа *tar* назначает каждому созданному файлу/каталогу именно те права, которые были записаны внутри архива.

> у папок и файлов был определенный владелец-пользователь?

программа *tar* (по крайней мере реализация от проекта *gnu*) при создании архива сохраняет информацию о владельце/группе файлов/каталогов не только в числовом виде (*uid/gid*), но и в виде строк. чтобы строки не сохранялись, можно воспользоваться опцией `--numeric-owner`.

при распаковке, запущенной от имени рядового пользователя, эта информация не оказывает (существенного) влияния, ведь рядовой пользователь может создавать файлы/каталоги, принадлежащие только ему.

при распаковке, запущенной от имени суперпользователя (у которого *uid* равен нулю; обычно в качестве имени этому пользователю назначается строка `root`), нет такого ограничения: процесс может создавать файлы/каталоги, принадлежащие пользователю/группе с любыми *uid/gid*.

соответственно, если в архиве были сохранены строки с именами владельцев/групп, то, при наличии пользователя/группы с таким именем в той системе, где выполняется распаковка, будут использованы эти имена.

если соответствующего имени пользователя/группы в этой системе нет (или имена вообще не были сохранены благодаря вышеупомянутой опции `--numeric-owner`), то будут использованы числовые значения, хранящиеся в архиве. а за этими числовыми значениями *uid/gid* могут быть закреплены совсем другие строки с именами пользователей/групп. вы, судя по всему, и столкнулись именно с такой ситуацией.

---

выход, фактически, один: до распаковки надо создать в этой системе пользователей/группы с теми именами, которые сохранены внутри архива.

посмотреть эти имена можно, добавив опцию `-v` при просмотре содержимого архива (а сам просмотр — это опция `-t`):

```
$ tar -t -v -f архив
```

пример вывода:

```
-rw-r--r-- user/group       0 2016-11-11 12:41 file
```

из которого видно, что файл `file` принадлежит пользователю `user`, группе `group`.